# With TKinter, how to reference controls created in loop on a grid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window=tk.Tk()
window.title('Test')
window.geometry("500x300")
window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

def check():
    pass

def uncheck():
    pass

for r in range(3):
    r+=1    
    chkVar = tk.IntVar()

    tk.Label(window, text='id'+str(r), relief='ridge', anchor='w', width=10).grid(row=r,column=1)    
    tk.Label(window, text='ttl'+str(r), relief='ridge', anchor='w', width=25).grid(row=r,column=2) 
    tk.Button(window, text='Check', width=11, command=lambda : check()).grid(row=r,column=3)
    tk.Checkbutton(window, text="", anchor='center', width=5, variable=chkVar).grid(row=r, column=4)    
    tk.Button(window, text='Uncheck', width=11, command=lambda : uncheck()).grid(row=r,column=5)

window.mainloop()
```

In the interface above, how do I let check/uncheck functions know to work with the checkbox in their own row?

But also, say I wanted to check or uncheck any particular box based on some condition not attached to a button on the row, then how would I acquire that specific control?

Thanks!

Comment: You can pass the instance of the checkbutton to the two functions.

Comment: Save the checkbuttons to a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def check(var):
    var.set(1)

def uncheck(var):
    var.set(0)

for r in range(3):
    .....

    tk.Button(window, text='Check', width=11, command=lambda chkVar=chkVar: check(chkVar)).grid(row=r,column=3)
    tk.Button(window, text='Uncheck', width=11, command=lambda chkVar=chkVar: uncheck(chkVar)).grid(row=r,column=5)
```

Here, you are passing the respective variables, stored inside their `lambdas` with `chkVar=chkVar`, onto the `check()`/`uncheck()`. Then setting it to 1 enables it, and 0 disables it.

How to reference the checkboxes made inside a loop? Make a list and store these inside the list.

```
def selector(): # Also could pass a parameter and then index list with it
    boxes[1].select() # This will select the 2nd box inside the list, if any

def deselector():
    boxes[1].deselect() # This will deselect the 2nd box inside the list, if any

boxes = []
for r in range(3):
    r+=1    
    chkVar = tk.IntVar()
    chk = tk.Checkbutton(window, text="", anchor='center', width=5, variable=chkVar)
    chk.grid(row=r, column=4)    
    boxes.append(chk)
```

1 is just an arbitrary number, you can change it according to the number of checkbox you want to refer to.

Comment: That is very nice and simple, and works! However, what about my other question, how would I check/uncheck any particular box from a non-button function? I suppose I would need some kind of control map.

Comment: @A.G. I dont understand what you mean, can you be more specific?

Comment: Let's say there's a function that runs not as a result of clicking one of the buttons, then how would one reference a specific checkbox?

Comment: @A.G. You mean how to reference the checkbox made in a loop? Check my updated answer.